# Business - plural form or singular form

Tags: grammar, difference

There are two sentences:

- I had some urgent ***business***

or

- I had some urgent **businesses**

What's the right?

(In the meaning that I was busy.)

Comment: We don't normally pluralise ***business*** in such contexts. You could say someone [*has an urgent affair to deal with*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+urgent+affair+to+deal+with%22), but we're more likely to pluralise that  one to [*urgent affairs to deal with.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22urgent+affairs+to+deal+with%22)

Comment: Stangdon's answer is correct, you can find additional information and examples regarding the use of "business" vs "businesses" right **[here](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00043.htm)**.

Answer (score 1):

The word **business** has several different meanings.  One is "commercial or mercantile activity engaged in as a means of livelihood".  So Microsoft is *a business*, Air India and Aeroflot are *businesses*, and so forth.  In this meaning, *business* is countable, and we have to use an article or counter with it.

Another meaning of business is "an immediate task or objective".  In this sense, *business* is usually **not** countable, so you do not pluralize it or use an article or counter.  "I have important business to do", but not "I have important businesses to do" or "I have several important businesses to do".

Saying "I had some businesses" would mean that you had several different companies.  But "urgent" doesn't really make sense in this context (how is a company urgent?) so the sentence is wrong.

We don't use **some** with singular nouns, but we do use it with uncountable nouns, so you can have "some business", just like you can have "some sand".

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that I wasn't be able to use business (in the meaning "affairs") with the plural form. Thank you, stangdon!